# What is the replacement for matching against floating-point values in OCaml?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I am learning [Jason Hickey's Introduction to Objective Caml](http://www.cs.caltech.edu/courses/cs134/cs134b/book.pdf).

---

It says

`Matching against floating-point values is supported, but it is rarely used because of numerical issues`

---

Ok, we can't match floating-point values.

**Then what if we need? How to do it then?**

Comment: The issue is unrelated to OCaml. A full explanation is in the paper: [What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/103162.103163).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on previous answers, you can use pattern matching with floats, like in this example:

```
# let float_match_example = function
    | 0. -> "exact zero"
    | x when abs_float x < 1e-12 -> "epsilon"
    | _ -> "other";;

val float_match_example : float -> string = <fun>

# List.map float_match_example [0.; 42e-15; 3.];;

- : string list = ["exact zero"; "epsilon"; "other"]
```

Just be careful that pattern matching implicitly uses equality test, which is rarely what one wants when working with floats: when rounding errors accumulate, two floats are rarely exactly equal. So, you can use [guards](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/expr.html#@manual.kwd43) with the keyword `when`, as illustrated in the above code.

Answer (score 4):

You can match floating point numbers, it just says it's rarely used.

It's rarely used because precision issues can occur.  If you have two numbers, x and y:

```
 x = 0.000000001
 y = 0.0000000009
```

Are x and y the same?  Well, it depends.  If x and y are the results of calculations, then accumulated rounding could explain the difference and they may be the same.

To put it more roughly, floating point comparisons are often "close enough" and hence why pattern matching would rarely use them as an exact match can exclude the "close enough" matches often required.

Answer (score 3):

You can write [pattern guards](https://code.google.com/p/ocaml-patterns/wiki/PatternGuards) with helper functions to check for equality, or being with some epsilon, or other criteria.

Answer (score 3):

When you work with algebraic data types (like `Some 3: int option`), pattern matching is actually required. It's the fundamental OCaml feature for getting at contained values. When working with primitive values like numbers, pattern matching is just a handy notation. The usual relational operators (and `if` statements) are available. That's what you usually use for floating-point values. As the other guys mentioned, you can also use pattern guards, which are mostly just another form of `if` statement.